# Is there a way to access google chrome browser print properties

Tags: javascript, css, browser, printing, properties

I am trying to customize the following to 85% and to print 1-sided to be de default for a bunch of printing jobs for my client. Is there a way that this can be done via javascript? I tried CSS but did not work out for me. If anyone has been able to do so, please let me know if this can be accomplished.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you cannot , as different browsers implement it different , you can only call window.print() but you can use tools like [CyPress](https://www.cypress.io/) or [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/get-started) to automate it , puppe